# application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation: nil annotation parameter on device

Tags: ios

I am launching my app from safari using `<a href="myApp://">Launch App</a>` and when the app enters `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` I need to find the address from which the app has been opened. In the iOS simulator I have the annotation parameter like this:

```
{
    ReferrerURL = "http://localhost:8080/";
}
```

but on a device annotation is nil. Any idea?

I would like to avoid to write the address as parameter inside href like `<a href="myApp://localhost/8080">Launch App</a>`

Comment: The annotation is a plist that is provided by the source app to pass information to the opened app. How safari will send you something it don't has? I think you will have to send it in the URL.

Comment: @MohamedElkassas But in the simulator it's sending the URL.

Comment: Can't find anything saying what will be included in the annotation list. it depends totally on the application sending it, and since you are not the one sending it, it has no standard format and you don't have any control on it , I don't think it's a good idea to depend on it in your code.